# NullPointerException on calling retrofit.Call<>

Tags: android, retrofit

I am using retrofit version "2.0.0-beta2" and converter-gson of the same version in an Android app.

I build the service in `onCreate` of a `Fragment`:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(getString(R.string.api_base_url))
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    mService = retrofit.create(MyService.class);
```

Then later on a UI event:

```
call = mService.method(params);
call.enqueue(methodCallback);
```

A few moments later, `onResponse` of the `methodCallback` is not invoked and the app crashes with the following backtrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at retrofit.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallback$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:86)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:177)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4947)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Am I using retrofit incorrectly or is this a possible bug?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrofit initialization seems ok , check if the callback is not null when you call "call.enqueue(methodCallback);"

Comment: All are Ok but still got an Issue.

Answer (score 0):

And make sure that callback's type is correct. If your call definition looks like this:

```
@GET("/api/rooms")
Call<List<Room>> getRooms(
);
```

Then the invoke should be:

```
retrofit.create(MyService.class).getRooms().enqueue(new Callback<List<Room>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<List<Room>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

For starters I would replace:

```
call.enqueue(methodCallback);
```

with an anonymous class and check if the service works.

Comment: I double checked the callback type, and secondly the type checking in the editor pretty much takes care of that as it is. E.g. I tried replacing with a different methodCallback and the editor reported that this enqueue could not be applied to the other callback type.